# How do I get the logs from a vSphere ESXi instance from before it was power-cycled?

Tags: vmware-esxi, log-files, vmware-vsphere

I've got a vSphere 4.1 ESXi test box here, and for some reason it went down at some point today. I turned it back on, but can't find out where it keeps its logs for the time when it became unavailable. Looking in `/var/log` every log seems to only start from the last time since it was power cycled, which is absolutely useless if I'm trying to find a log entry for the event which caused it to shut down.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We went through this with VMware support a few weeks ago, and their solution was to use an external syslog server. That obviously won't help you with this instance, but going forward you'll have all the logs.

Comment: Thanks. It's slightly ridiculous, but I'll just have to set up a syslog server just for this tiny environment.

Comment: Sorta ridiculous, yes, but it's generally a best practice to have a central syslog server, anyway...

Comment: are you saing that ESXi purges all the previous logs after reboot?

Comment: My understanding is that ESXi doesn't keep any logs on disk at all.